# I can not create a SingleChildScrollView screen on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to create a **scrollable screen**, **not the widgets inside** but the **whole screen** on Flutter but I get some errors like below:

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library ===================================================== RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#f643b relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1920
> pos 12: 'hasSize' The relevant error-causing widget was:
> SingleChildScrollView

Here is the code of one of the shown widgets:

```
var _settingsPage = StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              FloatingActionButton(
                                child: Icon(Icons.casino),
                                onPressed: changeHome,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            fit: FlexFit.loose,
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              child: Text(
                                _helpString,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                const Text('Is your character epic?'),
                                Checkbox(
                                  value: _epic,
                                  onChanged: (bool epic) {
                                    setState(
                                      () {
                                        _epic = epic;
                                      },
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `SingleChildScrollView` inside an `Expanded` widget?

Comment: or try putting the singleChildScrollView above the column

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `SingleChildScrollView` in a `SizedBox` with a defined height and width.

This will make sure your view is constructed to a defined space

To set SizedBox height to screen height you can use media query like
`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` and you can replace `height` with `width` to set the widget size to your screen width

If issue still persists feel free to comment
Regards,
Rachan